# Redirect user to another page - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I created a page, where user can register himself/herself. At the time of first login of user, user will redirect to add-profile page, where user can create his/her profile, after creation of profile user will redirect to another page which is account page where he/she can check his/her profile.

And my problem starts here, when the same user login his/her account second time, he/she will again redirect to add-profile page. But here i want to redirect user to account page, because user completed his/her profile page.

Does anyone know, how to achieve this? I mean what logic will be apply here.

Comment: when user login try to check out in back end that his profile is completed or not by adding an column in your table profile_complete. give thi value to 1 or 0 if 1 means it already competed his profile. now in login function check that user name password is correct ? if yes then profile is completed or not? if no then redirect to profile complete page otherwise on the page where you want.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I made a column named profile_complete and after completion of profile the value of profile_complete field is set to 1. How i create a query for this checking. This is my login query `$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");`

Comment: Can i write it as an answer?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Yes sure, profile table name is profile_description.

Comment: Please check, read and follow instruction also.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Complete login code is here: http://pastebin.com/yJRgwqJs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74545/discussion-between-novice-and-anant-kumar-singh).

Comment: Do you have to write `his/her` all the time?

Comment: @Cthulhu Yes because i am novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple possible solutions and it all depends on your project requirement.

A possible solution is, you can create a flag/status column in your table which says about the basic completion of user profile.

Means you can set its value to true when user has submitted some basic details that is mandatory for your project. In that case you can redirect user to some other page else redirect to add profile page.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to add a new field and if the user completed the profile page set the field value as `1`. After logging in you check the field and if it set to `1` redirect it to the account page. That is it

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, you just have to create an extra column named as `user_profile_complete` in your user database table, which takes boolean values (i.e True/False). **True** value means user completed it's profile while **False** means not completed yet it's profile.By default , you have to set it's value as **Flase**.

So after user registeration, you know to redirect user to fill profile details page. But, when after user login,  first you have to check whether user completed it's profile or not by checking the `user_profile_complete` column (Note:- you can query to get `user_profile_complete` field value at login time or you can create separate query).If `user_profile_complete` is **False** , you have to redirect user to fill profile details page, otherwise redirect to it profile page.